# Replace image with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, widget

I am trying to replace an img tag with a specific src tag with an iframe using JQuery.
This is part of an external widget script implementation. This is the code I'm using to replace the image with a specific src with an iframe:

```
function main() {
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var img = $("img[src='http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs17/f/2007/129/7/4/Stock_032__by_enchanted_stock.jpg']")[0];
  var width;
  var height;
  var id = 47;
  $("<img/>") 
      .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
      .load(function() {
          width = this.width;   
          height = this.height; 
          var widgetReplace = "<iframe src=&quothttp://localhost:5000/app/#/widget" + id + "?height=" + height + "px&width=" + width + "px frameborder='0' height=&quot" + height + "&quot width=&quot" + width + "&quot style='overflow:'hidden';&quot></iframe>"; 
          this.replaceWith(widgetReplace);
      });        
   });
  }
})();
```

I am getting an error "Undefined is not a function" at the `this.replaceWith(widgetReplace)` line.

Comment: "an error" — **What** error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method replaceWith() is a jQuery function, so you should use:

```
$(this).replaceWith(widgetReplace);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Hmm, after i posted saw the error was not what I beleived it was, guess I'm wrong then.

I may be completely wrong due to the formatting of the iframe but from looking at it for a minute or two it appears you are missing a &quot.
 Here is the line in question, i cut alot of it off to be easier to read

```
var widgetReplace = "<iframe src=&quothttp://localhost:5000/app/#/widget" + id + "?height="
```

After the id or ? I believe should be the end quote to complete the src. E.G.

```
"<iframe src=&quothttp://localhost:5000/app/#/widget" + id + "?&quotheight="
```

Of course depending on the fromatting the &quot could be in a different place, I have no way to know.